# Button states persist through clicking?

Tags: css, mobile

I noticed that on Iphone my button states are acting a little funny.

here's what's set up:

```
<button class="button follow">follow</button>
<button class="button unfollow" style>unfollow</button>
```

css:

```
.button {
  background: green;
}

.button:hover, .button:active {
  red;
}
```

when the buttons are clicked they perform an ajax function and alternate. I.E. if follow is showing and i click follow the ajax call is made and follow is hidden and unfollow is shown and vice versa.

My conundrum:

In mobile when I click a button the buttons swap, but the new button is rendered in it's active state (i.e. the background is red).

any idea on how to make sure the button does not get rendered in it's hovered/active state?